# groovy method scope when using a method reference

Tags: dynamic, methods, groovy

I have a groovy class that looks up a method reference and then invokes it. The method being invoked is a private method. When the actual class is an instance of the child class, it throws an error that it cannot find the private method, even though it is the public method in the parent that actually calls it.

In this case, I could obviously just call `pMethod2()` directly and that works, but I'm trying to understand why this doesn't work as written and if there's a way to correct it so it works.

```
class Parent {

  def pMethod1() {
    def m = this.&pMethod2
    m() // this call fails if the calling class is of type Child
  }


  private def pMethod2() {}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Child().pMethod1();
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bit confusing, especially if you're used to C / C++. What you get when using the ".&" operator in Groovy is not an address, but an instance of MethodClosure.

The MethodClosure object contains an owner and a delegate object, which is used when resolving the method to call. In your example, the owner and delegate object will be "this", which is an instance of Child. The method to call is simply stored as a string.

So, the assignment

```
m = this.&pMethod2
```

is just a shorthand way of writing

```
m = new MethodClosure(this, "pMethod2")
```

When you invoke the m() closure, it will try to resolve (at runtime) the method by looking for methods named "pMethod2" in the owner and the delegate objects respectively. Since the owner and delegate is an instance of Child, it will not find private methods located in Parent.

To make your example work you must make sure that the method is visible to the owner and/or delegate of the closure.

This can be done several ways, for instance by changing the access modifier of pMethod2 to protected, or by creating the closure with an instance of Parent; something like this:

```
m = new Parent().&pMethod2
```

Note that is is irrelevant that you created the MethodClosure instance in a method where pMethod2 is actually visible. It is also irrelevant that you invoke the closure in a method where it is visible. The method is not visible to the owner or delegate of the MethodClosure, which is what is being used when resolving the method.